# Notepad++ grouping/capture not working

Tags: notepad++, regex

A regular expression such as "**(Received):**" should match every "**Received**" that precedes a "**:**".

N++ is finding for me the whole string: "**Received:**" So instead of highlighting in my document "**Received**" I am getting "**Received:**". What's happening? Find and Replace behaves the same.

I am using version 6.5.5 (UNICODE).

Comment: You are asking it to match `Received` **followed** by `:` (colon) and that is **exactly** what it is doing. If you want to match just `Received` then use `(Received)` **not** `(Received):`

Comment: No, I am asking it to 1) match the word Received 2) only those that precede a colon. ps I don't know why N++ is highlighting the colon also, since it's not in parens.

Comment: That **is** what it is matching. The **colon** is **part of the match** you asked for. It is **not part** of the group expression `(...)` which is intended to be used **in the replace with field.**

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Full tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: David, I appreciate your help here. Correct me if I am wrong, but N++'s highlighting is confusing the matter (selects the entire regex instead of what is in the parens). My understanding of parens: they mean "take what you want" from an expression.

Comment: That how the highlighting is intended to work. It matches the complete regular expression not bits of it.

Comment: The group expression just stores the match for later. It has nothing to do with highlighting of the whole regular expression match.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html: "Positive lookahead works just the same. q(?=u) matches a q that is followed by a u, **without making the u part of the match**. The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegEx feature you are looking at is a [Positive Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). If you search for `(Received)(?=:)` in:

```
Received
Received:
[Received]
Received:
```

only 2-nd and 4-th line `Received` will match.

---

You have missed a point of () groups a bit.

Grouping by () allows you to capture a characters from inside of a group and use them later.

Try to replace `([\d]+):` with `prefix_\1_suffix` in:

```
12343:
123a:
1111:
222
333:
```

And you should get:

```
prefix_12343_suffix
123a:
prefix_1111_suffix
222
prefix_333_suffix
```

Comment: "to capture characters ... and use them later". Ok, for extraction. I thought they were the subexpression to be replaced by another.

Comment: what is "regex future"?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: "Positive lookahead works just the same. q(?=u) matches a q that is followed by a u, without making the u part of the match. The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign."

Comment: @sasha Groups are subexpressions, but the whole point of it is that you can reference to them later. I mean "feature".